# Doesn't hold the values after submission or reload

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have added a property to hold the values of a list, but when I submit the form or reload the page, it returns null for property `Courts` and doesn't keep the values.

This is my code

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Courts> Courts { get; set; } // Define the property

// Existing request property
[BindProperty]
public BookRequest Request { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    if (Courts == null) // Load the courts only if it's not already loaded
    {
        Courts = (List<Courts>)await _requestRepository.GetAllCourtsAsync();
    }

    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Courts == null) // Load the courts only if it's not already loaded
        {
            Courts = (List<Courts>)await _requestRepository.GetAllCourtsAsync();
        }

        return Page();
    }

    try
    {
        // Save the request to the database
        await _requestRepository.AddAsync(Request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewData["Notification"] = new Notification
        {
            Type = Enums.NotificationType.Error,
            Message = "Something went wrong" + ex.Message
        };

        return Page();
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./List");
}
```

And this is a part of the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Request.CourtId">Court</label>
    <select asp-for="Request.CourtId" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select a court</option>
        @foreach (var court in Model.Courts)
        {
            <option value="@court.Id">@court.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Request.CourtId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

What would be the case ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have added a property to hold the values of a list, but when I
> submit the form or reload the page, it returns null for property
> Courts and doesn't keep the values.

Well, Did you mean List Courts would persist its value even after reloading the page? If so, you got it wrong, asp.net core page life cycle doesn't works this way, once the from submitted which means the end of life cycle, either by pulling data, or updating something or inserting.

Therefore, if the page been reloaded, this List Courts no longer can keep the value its stateless, or cannot keep the state.

However, if you want to help the value even after the page reload or end of life cycle, we must use session in order to keep the state.

Let's have a look in practice how we can achieve that.

Static class for managing session object:

Well, in order to maintain value in session we should have a static class for setting and retrieving value into session. We can do as following:

```
public static class SessionExtensionForHoldingValue
{
    //setting session
    public static void SetValuesInSession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    //getting session
    public static T? GetValuesFromSession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Method for using session pulling and pushing value into session:

```
public void HoldsValue(Courts courts)
{

    var getCurrentValues = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<CourtsObject>("CourtsObject");
    if (getCurrentValues != null)
    {
        getCurrentValues!.CourtsItem!.Add(courts);
        HttpContext.Session.SetComplexObjectSession("CourtsObject", getCurrentValues);
    }
    else
    {
        getCurrentValues = new CourtsObject();
        getCurrentValues!.CourtsItem!.Add(courts);
        HttpContext.Session.SetComplexObjectSession("CourtsObject", getCurrentValues);
    }

}
```

Call within your Task OnPostAsync() Method:

```
//Getting older value
var getPreviousValues = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<CourtsObject>("CourtsObject");
//Holding submitted value 
var submittedValue = new Courts();
submittedValue.CourtId = Request.CourtId;
HoldsValue(submittedValue);
//Checking full value
var getCurrentValues = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexObjectSession<CourtsObject>("CourtsObject");
```

Program.cs:

[Use following middleware reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-session-state) in your program.cs file:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) if you need more details on [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: ok thank you that works , but can you do a more simple solution with tempData? i tried it tho but it wasnt consistent. Can you tell me your thoughts ?

Comment: Same things for viewBag and tempData, ViewData, once the page life cycles ends, no longer the data would be kept. So, until the page not refreshed you can use them but if you need your data as long as you want then  the session and cookies are the most used way.

Comment: The TenpData with the use of .keep() and .peak() cant hold data  between requests ?

Comment: Yeah they do, you can use them but only alive up to next request no more than that.